# How to create a clickable, visible but obfuscated mailto:// link

Tags: css, obfuscation

I know there's already a lot about email obfuscation on this site. But recently I found this neat little `CSS-trick` that I hadn't encountered before.

It SHOWS the email address (here: user@domain.com), but sadly it doesn't produce a clickable `mailto://` link. If one entered it as a `href`, of course the address would again be ready for bots to be picked up.

So I added a litte javascript routine, that adds an event listener to all `.e-mail` elements:

```js
// Email de-obfuscation, start mail client, copy email to clipboard:

document.querySelectorAll('.e-mail').forEach(e => { 

    // get the encoded email address from ::after and decode:

    function getDecodeEmail(event) {
        z=event.currentTarget;
        y=getComputedStyle(z,'::after');
        x=y.getPropertyValue('content');
        // reverse string rtl
        v=x.split("").reverse().join("");
        // remove all "
        return v.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
    };
    
    // onClick start mail client with decoded email address:

    e.addEventListener("click", event => {
        // prevent href=#
        event.preventDefault();
        // get the (reversed) email address of the calling anchor
        v=getDecodeEmail(event);
        //window.location.href="mailto:"+v;
        // former statement doesn't fire in SE code snippets, 
        // but you can try here: https://jsfiddle.net/jamacoe/Lp4bvn13/75/
        // for now, let's just display the link:
        alert("mailto:"+v);
    });

    // right mouse click copies email to clipboard:

    e.addEventListener("contextmenu", event => {
        // prevent href=#
        event.preventDefault();
        // get the (reversed) email address of the calling anchor
        v=getDecodeEmail(event);
        // copy v to clipboard
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(v);
        // just to check:
        navigator.clipboard.readText().then( clipText => alert(clipText) );
        // former statements don't work in SE code snippets,
        // but you can try here: https://jsfiddle.net/jamacoe/Lp4bvn13/75/

    });
});
```

```css
.e-mail::after {
  content: attr(data-mailSvr) "\0040" attr(data-mailUsr);
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<a class=e-mail data-mailUsr=resu data-mailSvr=moc.niamod href=""></a>
```

On the one hand side I'm very content with this solution. But on the other hand, I think my javascript spoils the elegance and simplicity of the HTML/CSS. Does anybody have an idea how to complement **this approach** of email obfuscation, only using pure CSS + HTML, resulting in a clickable and visable link that meets all common requirements (i.e. screen reader compatible, sufficiently obfuscated, correctly formatted, right clickable for copying)?

Comment: This is not possible with pure HTML + CSS. To initiate a mail client, you have to use the mailto protocol in an href/redirect with JS similar to the way you did.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar in the past. I needed a way to display my email address on one of my websites, but not get horribly spammed in the process. I implemented this 2 years ago, and I haven't received any spam. I didn't do this with CSS though... this is pure JS.

If you hover over the result, you'll see that it creates a clickable email address.

Hope this helps.

```js
let fname = "first";
let lname = "last";
let domain = "gmail.com";

email.innerHTML = `<a href="mailto:${fname}.${lname}@${domain}">${fname}.${lname}@${domain}</a>`;
```

```html
<span id="email"></span>
```